# Unique constraint for two columns in Mysql and indexes

Tags: mysql

Sorry for newbie question - am I understand right that these two operators are identical in Mysql?

```
ALTER TABLE friends ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (`user_id`, `friend_id`);
```

and

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX friends_user_friend ON friends (user_id, friend_id);
```

Answer (score 4):

yes !

only CREATE INDEX cannot be used to create a PRIMARY KEY, use ALTER TABLE instead

read more in :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html